# How to refresh Messages on Mac after hibernation?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios

I've set up iMessage on my iPhone correctly (apple id) with Messages on my Mac (OSX Mountain Lion), and it syncs.

But the syncing isn't flawless.. Everytime I wake up my Mac after hibernation, it won't update my messages. I first have to restart the app a few times, to get all my messages. Sometimes even the order of the messages isn't correct.

From my experience the syncing is still quite buggy.

Does anyone have the same issues, and maybe a workaround?

ps: I don't use wifi on my Mac, if that's relevant.

Comment: I've had some trouble with Messages syncing correctly as well. It really bothers me when they come in out of order. I have noticed that sometimes, if you just leave it open for awhile, most of them will come in on their own.

Comment: Indeed, but not always. And when it does, it takes up to 10 minutes. This is far from the experience I expect from Apple.

Comment: Agreed. Totally.

Comment: This also seems to happen on my iPad. Usually my iPhone is fine, but iPad and Mac are sometimes incomplete or out of order.

Comment: iMessage has lots of bugs with syncing and delivery. You should send Apple [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) or a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) (requires free developer account) so they know it's an issue.

Comment: I experience wrong order every time I open the Message app after a notification. That's pretty annoying, actually

Comment: This has apparently been fixed in 10.8.4. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1590758

Answer (score 4):

The closest solution I found is to ping one of your connections.

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll up and down consistently in the sidebar (where all the convos are held) for a while it usually tends to send and receive. At first it might only do one side of the messages, but keep scrolling up and down and it will eventually all be there. Takes less than 15 seconds at most.

Answer (score 0):

the messages app is always slow, restart it (and wait a long time).

Comment: Exactly, but it's annoying restarting it several times.

Comment: But this IS the answer.  The messages app is always slow.  You cannot force reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it. It's the server side that is laggy. When All my iMessage devices are off at the same time, I'll receive all my messages at the same time hours after the actual time

Answer (score -2):

restart your computer and just keep clicking on and off the message icon

Answer (score -2):

close the messages app & press command + Q and click on the messages. a applications window will pop up so just open your iMessage from there. works sometimes.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more details how this procedure works?